# How to write an installer for 64-bit project on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-project

I want to generate an *.msi installer for my 64-bit C++ project which I created using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition. But when I use "Setup Wizard" and create a deployment project, it's automatically targeting x86 platform and there is no way to change this setting to x64.

How can I change this setting, and how can I generate an installer for my project?

Comment: Select the Setup project in the Solution Explorer window.  Change the TargetPlatform property from x86 to x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the setup project type built into visual studio. It is extremely limiting.

Instead download and install [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It integrates into visual studio but instead of building an installer through a simple drag & drop interface, you will have to write XML. It has a bit of a learning curve, but you will have total control over the installation process.